# TSQL connection refused - host command DNS resolve issue in local network

Tags: vmware, dns

I am using VMWare Starter and running 2 guest VMs, Ubuntu and Windows XP Professional. The host system is Windows 7.

Windows XP Professional hosts MSSQL database, Ubuntu talks to it using FreeTDS.

Unfortunately I can not connect using:

```
tsql -S windog -U sa
```

because it fails:

```
Password: 
locale is "en_GB.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
Error 20009 (severity 9):
Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist
OS error 111, "Connection refused"
There was a problem connecting to the server
```

I've found nice page that describes how to debug the TSQL issues:
http://www.freetds.org/userguide/confirminstall.htm

I've found that problem is that "**host**" linux command which TSQL probably relies on does not respect the entries in /etc/hosts.

```
> host 9E37F01AB
has address 81.200.64.50
Host 9E37F01AB not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

Above IP looks like is my ISP fallback IP for not found DNS entries.

However ping resolve the IP to 192.168.0.7 (which is correct)

My configs looks like this:

/etc/hosts

```
 192.168.0.7 9E37F01AB
```

/etc/freetds/freetds.conf

```
[windog]
host = 9E37F01AB
instance = SQL2008EXPRESS
port = 1433
tds version = 7.0
client charset = UTF-8
```

How do I manage that to work with not too much hassle?

Previously it worked, but I've had the router on OpenWRT with DNSMasq running, so it was adding all my network machine hostnames to the router DNS.